# How to merge two json Strings into one in java

Tags: java, json

If we have given 2 Strings of type json, how can we merge them into single json String in java?

```
e.g. 

    String json1 = {
        "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDiv": {
                "title": "S"
            }
        }
    }

String json2 = {
        "glossary": {
            "title": "person name",
            "age":  "25"
        }
    }
```

Should produce

```
String mergedJson = {
   "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDiv": {
                "title": "S"
            },
            "age":  "25"
        }
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in functionality for that. Take the 2 nodes, loop over the children of node a and see if they also exist in node b. If so, merge them recursively. Then loop over the remaining nodes of node b. That gives you a merged node c.

Comment: What are conditions when `title` would be repaced?

Comment: You should do this manually by converting JSON to Glossary objects and applying wanted rules in copy method that you will write. It would be safer, cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code which recursively merges two jsons. This outputs as excepted:
NOTE: This is **deep merge**, not shallow merge ( similar concept used for shall vs deep copy)

```
private static JsonObject merge(JsonObject json1Obj, JsonObject json2Obj) {

        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet1 = json1Obj.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet1) {
            String key1 = entry.getKey();
            if (json2Obj.get(key1) != null) {
                JsonElement tempEle2 = json2Obj.get(key1);
                JsonElement tempEle1 = entry.getValue();
                if (tempEle2.isJsonObject() && tempEle1.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject mergedObj = merge(tempEle1.getAsJsonObject(),
                            tempEle2.getAsJsonObject());
                    entry.setValue(mergedObj);
                }
            }
        }

        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet2 = json2Obj.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet2) {
            String key2 = entry.getKey();
            if (json1Obj.get(key2) == null) {
                json1Obj.add(key2, entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return json1Obj;
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: This is deep merge, not shallow merge ( similar concept used for shall vs deep copy)

Answer (score 7):

Below code should do it, with a couple of assumptions:

- You are using ObjectMapper of Jackson library (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`) to serialise/deserialise json
- fields of json1 will always overwrite json2 while merging

  ```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Map<String, Object> map1 = mapper.readValue("json1", Map.class);
  Map<String, Object> map2 = mapper.readValue("json2", Map.class);
  Map<String, Object> merged = new HashMap<String, Object>(map2);
  merged.putAll(map1);
  System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(merged));
  ```

Comment: But this is not excepted result. This is producing:                 `{"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S"}}}`

Comment: I will write my own java code to do it manually as told by @agilob

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a library that does this job for you, like [JSON Merge](https://github.com/oswaldobapvicjr/jsonmerge/), available at Maven Central.

You will get the desired result with a single line of code (you may ignore the String declarations if you already have the JSONObjects previously loaded):

```
String json1 = "{\n"
        + "        \"glossary\": {\n"
        + "            \"title\": \"example glossary\",\n"
        + "            \"GlossDiv\": {\n"
        + "                \"title\": \"S\"\n"
        + "            }\n"
        + "        }\n"
        + "    }";

String json2 = "{\n"
        + "        \"glossary\": {\n"
        + "            \"title\": \"person name\",\n"
        + "            \"age\":  \"25\"\n"
        + "        }\n"
        + "    }";

JSONObject result = new JsonMerger<>(JSONObject.class).merge(json2, json1);
```

**Note:** the first JSON parameter passed to the `merge` method will always have more precedence/importance than the second one in case of key collisions.

This library works with Jackson, Gson, and other JSON providers as well.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm quite late to the party but I wanted to share my solution if anybody stumbles across this.
You can deeply merge two json strings with `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` `ObjectMapper.readerForUpdating()`.

In this scenario you pass in two Json as String and merge them via readerForUpdating (untested code):

```
public String mergeJsonStrings(String json1, String json2) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerForUpdating(json1);
    String result = reader.readValue(json2);
    return result;
}
```

I used similar code to merge a property into an existing dataset. In this example the `SomeProperties` class contains a hashmap which holds the properties for a specific user. The passed in `propertiesString` is a single dot separated property e.g. `some.random.property=value`. The property will be transformed into a `JsonNode` with `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-properties`.

```
public SomeProperties mergeProperties(SomeProperties someProperties, String propertiesString) {
    JavaPropsMapper javaPropsMapper = new JavaPropsMapper();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = javaPropsMapper.readTree(propertiesString);
    ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.readerForUpdating(someProperties.getProperties());
    HashMap<String, Object> mergedProperties = objectReader.readValue(jsonNode);
    someProperties.setProperties(mergedProperties);
    return someProperties;
}
```

In both cases everything passed into `objectReader.readValue()` will override existing keys.