# Merging JSON result in java

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-cloud

I've two JSONObjects as listed below

```
ProductionCast castDetails =restTemplate.getForObject(url, ProductionCast.class);
MovieDetails movieDetails = movieDao.getDetailsOfCast(id).orElse(new MovieDetails());

//more code
return list;  //list of two objects *List<Object>*
```

The result is coming like:

```
{"
movieId":1001,
"movieName":"Bahubali"
//little more details
}
{
"movieId":1001,
"Director":"Rajamouli"
//little more details
}
```

I want the result like:

```
{
"movieId":1001,
"movieName":"Bahubali",
"director":"Rajamouli"
//little more details
}
```

is there anything i can do to merge the JSON result? i want to merge that based on "movieId".

Edit: My question has been identified as duplicate. here i want to merge the objects which are returning the result in JSON format using @RestController. I'm not using any kind of JSON objects. Hope you understood.

Comment: you are returning list, but how are you preparing the list ? Please show that part

Comment: by creating List<Object> and adding those two objects

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747813/how-to-merge-two-json-strings-into-one-in-java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two json Strings into one in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747813/how-to-merge-two-json-strings-into-one-in-java)

Comment: I've tried the link you provided already. Still haven't got the proper answer so i posted it here. Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 2):

if you want merge to different entity when return.

you can try `@JsonUnwrapped`

```java
  public class Result{
   @JsonUnwrapped
   private ProductionCast castDetails;

   @JsonUnwrapped
   private MovieDetails movieDetails
  }
```

It's going to return

```
{
"movieId":1001,
"movieName":"Bahubali",
"director":"Rajamouli"
}
```

need attention. the `@JsonUnwrapped` can't  be applied on `List`

Comment: It is displaying movieId 2 times.
{"movieId": 1001,
    "movieName": "chirutha",
     "movieId": 1001,
     "director": "Puri Jagannath"}

Answer (score 0):

Create a dto class which has movieId, movieName and director fields. Create instance of it with your castDetails and movieDetails objects fields above and return dto object

Comment: this is good when i have 3 fields as you said. what if i have 100 fields do i need to use setters for all of them? as all the fields will be in private.

Comment: Good point. Using Builder pattern would be a solution for not using all fields setters when you create your dto object

Answer (score 0):

You can do a UNION (combine without duplicates) by putting all your values in a HashMap. Any equal keys will be overwritten. Here is an example using [four different ways](https://crunchify.com/in-java-how-to-convert-map-hashmap-to-jsonobject-4-different-ways/) (GSON, org.json, jackson-core and json-simple) to create your JSON from the map.

Here is a working sample. I am using reflection to fill the map. That might not be what you want.

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IllegalAccessException {

    ProductionCast productionCast = new ProductionCast("1001", "Rajamouli");
    MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails("1001", "Bahubali");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    fillMap(map, productionCast);
    fillMap(map, movieDetails);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map));

  }

  private static void fillMap(Map<String, String> map, Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field:fields) {
        map.put(field.getName(), (String) field.get(object));
    }
  }

  private static class ProductionCast {
    public ProductionCast(String movieId, String director) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.director = director;
    }

    public String getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    private String movieId;
    private String director;
  }

  private static class MovieDetails {
    private String movieId;
    private String movieName;


    public MovieDetails(String movieId, String movieName) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }

    public String getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public String getMovieName() {
        return movieName;
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "director" : "Rajamouli",
  "movieId" : "1001",
  "movieName" : "Bahubali"
}
```