# How to merge two JSON string

Tags: java, json

I have two JSON strings, I want to merge these two response string into a single one. Is there any way to merge these two JSON string using java ?

```
String str1 = "{
                "data" : { 
                        "values" : {
                            "name" : "kiran",
                            "age"  : "24"
                        }
                        }
                        }"
                        
String str2 = "{
                "data" : { 
                        "values" : {
                            "name" : "Mamu",
                            "age"  : "26"
                        }
                        }
                        }"
```

I wnat to merge these two JSON string as follows

```
String mergeResult = "{
                "data" : { 
                        "values" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "kiran",
                            "age"  : "24"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "Manu",
                            "age"  : "26"
                        }
                        ]
                        }
                        }"
```

Comment: Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747813/how-to-merge-two-json-strings-into-one-in-java

Answer (score 1):

From your example JSON it looks like there can be many more input objects than two, so I'd use a JSON to JSON transform via JOLT library (https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) as follows:

1. Form a JSON array of all the input `{"data" : ...}` objects (either by collecting the original objects and putting them in a `List` before serialization or just manually by concatenating their JSONs with square brackets):

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "values": {
        "name": "kiran",
        "age": "24"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "values": {
        "name": "Mamu",
        "age": "26"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

2. Use the JOLT spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "data": {
          "values": {
            "@": "data.values[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The resulting JSON:

```json
{
  "data" : {
    "values" : [ {
      "name" : "kiran",
      "age" : "24"
    }, {
      "name" : "Mamu",
      "age" : "26"
    } ]
  }
}
```

You can test or modify the spec yourself at http://jolt-demo.appspot.com before using it in your application.

Here's what Java side might look like:

```java
Resource transformationSpec = ...
String inputJson = ...
List<Object> specs = JsonUtils.jsonToList(transformationSpec.getInputStream());
Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
Object inputObject = JsonUtils.jsonToObject(inputJson);
Object transformedObject = chainr.transform(inputObject);
String transformedJson = JsonUtils.toJsonString(transformedObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Library *Josson & Jossons* has concatenate operation to combine array from datasets.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("resp1", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"data\": {" +
    "        \"values\": {" +
    "            \"name\": \"kiran\"," +
    "            \"age\": \"24\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    }" +
    "}"));
jossons.putDataset("resp2", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"data\": {" +
    "        \"values\": {" +
    "            \"name\": \"Mamu\"," +
    "            \"age\": \"26\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    }" +
    "}"));
    
JsonNode mergeValues = jossons.evaluateQuery(
    "resp1->data.toArray() <+< resp2->data.toArray()");
System.out.println(mergeValues.toPrettyString());

JsonNode mergeResult = Josson.create(mergeValues).getNode(
    "toObject('values').toObject('data')");
System.out.println(mergeResult.toPrettyString());
```

mergeValues

```
[ {
  "name" : "kiran",
  "age" : "24"
}, {
  "name" : "Mamu",
  "age" : "26"
} ]
```

mergeResult

```
{
  "data" : {
    "values" : [ {
      "name" : "kiran",
      "age" : "24"
    }, {
      "name" : "Mamu",
      "age" : "26"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be not the most efficient solution but very simple one would be to parse each String into a Map (or specific POJO if you have one) and merge them as maps, and than serialize back into Json String. To parse a json string to map or a specific POJO you can use Jackson library - method [readValue() of ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) Or [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) library. Also, I wrote my own simple wrapper over Jackson library that simplifies the use. Class [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) is available as part of MgntUtils library (written and maintained by me). This class just has the methods that allow you to parse and de-serialize from/to Json String from/to a class instance. So your code could be as follows:

```
public String mergeJsonStrings(String str1, Str2) throws IOException {
  Map<String, Object> map1 = convertJsonStringToMap(str1);
  Map<String, Object> map2 = convertJsonStringToMap(str2);
  Map<String, Object> dataMap1 = (Map<String, Object>)map1.get("data");
  Map<String, Object> valuesMap1 = (Map<String, Object>)dataMap1.get("values");
  Map<String, Object> dataMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)map2.get("data");
  Map<String, Object> valuesMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)dataMap2.get("values");
  valuesMap1.putAll(valuesMap2);
  return convertMapToJsonString(map1);
}


  Map<String, Object> convertJsonStringToMap(String str) throws IOException {
    return JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(str, Map.class);
  }

  Strong convertMapToJsonString(Map<String,Object> map) throws JsonProcessingException{
    return JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(map); 
  }
```

This example uses MgntUtils library to parse and serialize JSON but of course you can use Jackson, Gson or any other library you want. MgntUtils library available as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)